# Positioning item (html, css, js included)

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I'm having a problem with positioning item in webpage. Im using Foundation 5. The problem is the twitter icon which i cannot get positioned inline with the twitter feed text.

JSFIDDLE:  http://jsfiddle.net/8hux4/1/

Help appreciated!

```
just here to let post jsfiddle
```

Here you can see the problem http://teamblackops.arkku.net/testi/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle does not display anything...

So i looked for your test page and you icon is inline but this not near the feed text, cause your small-2 block is too large.
You could:

- Use width: auto; on it
- Use text-align: right; on it